# Suppose $f(z) = u+ iv$ is an analyic function in a domain $D$. If $u-v = e^{x} ( \cos y - \sin y )$. Find $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

We wish to find $f(z)$.

$f= u+ iv$, we have $if = -v + iu$.

$\Re[(1+i)f(z)] = e^{x} (\cos y -\sin y)$.

This is what I did, how do I continue please?

Comment: $f(z)=e^{z}+(1+i)c$ where $c$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good starting point. Now, let $U(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}\bigl((1+i)f(x+yi)\bigr)=e^x(\cos(y)-\sin(y))$ and let $V(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}\bigl((1+i)f(x+yi)\bigr)$. Then$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=e^x(\cos(y)-\sin(y))$$and therefore$$V(x,y)=e^x(\sin(y)+\cos(y))+C(x),$$for some differentiable function $C$. Then$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=e^x(\sin(y)+\cos(y))+C'(x),$$but you also have$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=e^x(\sin(y)+\cos(y)),$$And therefore $C'=0$. So,$$(1+i)f(x+yi)=e^x(\cos(y)-\sin(y))+\bigl(e^x(\sin(y)+\cos(y))+K\bigr)i,$$for some $K\in\Bbb R$, and therefore$$f(z)=e^z+\omega$$with $\omega\in\Bbb C$ such that $\operatorname{Re}\omega=\operatorname{Im}\omega$.